# Connected to Turbo VPN - 10.13.0.42/30. Tap to manage the network

Tags: networking, mobile-network, vpn

When I use a VPN app on my smartphone, the following notification message is shown

> Connected to Turbo VPN - 10.13.0.42/30. Tap to manage the network

Why is it connected to `10.*.*.*`? Isn't it a private network?

I'm using Turbo VPN 2.6.3

Comment: Yes VPN is a Private Network, not public. And 10.*.*.* is from private IP pool just like 192.168.*.* we usually have with routers. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network